# How to implement Naminig Strategy in hibernate 3 with entity manager?

Tags: spring, hibernate-entitymanager, hibernate3

I want to change the column name("size") for entity class, size is a keyword in oracle so i want to modify at runtime via NamingStrategy.

But unable to success.

I have added a property in my persistence.xml.

```
"<property name="hibernate.naming-strategy" value="com.group.myStrategy" />"
```

I have extends DefaultNamingStrategy, no success the methods wasnt calling.

Please suggest how to implement in hibernate 3.2 ga.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hope this helps: https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/tips-and-tricks/implementing-a-custom-namingstrategy-with-hibernate/

Comment: Thanks joe, i was using the property name as "hibernate.naming-strategy" but actual needed was  "hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy".